# SceneKit Unit of Measure

Tags: ios, iphone, scenekit

If I was to create a SCNBox geometry in SceneKit with a width, height and length of 5, how does this translate to real world measurements?

For example, what measurements would I use to create the same size cube in say SketchUp?

Does 1 unit in SceneKit equal 10mm or 100mm?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

in SceneKit distances are specified in meters.
So your box would be 5m wide.

Comment: Any idea how to go from meters to pixels?